# Change backcolor or hide border in Telerik radPageView

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, telerik

I want to change color or remove the green border of tab. How can i do this? I use Telerik PageView in strip mode.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: is the site live?if it is..within 5 minutes i would be able to fix for sure...or any reproducable scenario...

Comment: This seems like a winforms app. Still we need a reproducible scenario to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the followimg CSS and markup

```
.multiPage
    {
      border:none !important;//to remove the green border
      background:green !important;/to change the background color
    }
```

aspx:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1" 
       CssClass="multiPage">
        ..................
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Comment: this is a windows application not web.